# excel file not found when referenced run time error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to run a macro, but when referencing a excel file I have set up already I am getting a run time error and highlights which references my path. I am almost certain that this path is correct because I went to the properties of the excel file and copied the location

```
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
```

---

```
' Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 Debug.Print strPath = enviro & "\Documents\multipliers.xls"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Test1")
    ' Process the message record
```

[image: Location]

Comment: the 'strPath = enviro & "C:\Users\ltorres\Documents\multipliers.xls"' creates a string like this 'C:\Users\ltorres\C:\Users\ltorres\Documents\multipliers.xls'

Comment: @gizlmeier I have removed C:\Users\ltorres\ from strPath = enviro & "C:\Users\ltorres\Documents\multipliers.xls and still getting a error on Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

Comment: Then you're probably missing a \ before `Documents`

Comment: To remove doubt, why not write `Debug.Print strPath`, then check the Immediate window to see what is written. Does that match what you think it should be? If not, make corrections.

Comment: @Rory I have edited my post to how my code looks now with still no luck and I have also used Debug.Print and I am getting a False on Immediate window

Comment: @user3561813 I am getting a false on Immediate window

Comment: change your debug.print line from `Debug.Print strPath = enviro & "\Documents\multipliers.xls"`to two line, one with `strPath = enviro & "\Documents\multipliers.xls"` and the other with `Debug.Print strPath`. Right now our are printing the result from the comparaison of `strPath` and `enviro & "\Documents\multipliers.xls"`

Comment: @VincentG that still only produces a false on immediate window

Comment: You could always try:
`Debug.print Dir(strPath)`
To see if excel can find the file you are trying to open with that particular path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is a `.xlsx` file, not `.xls` as in your code. Change the following line:

```
strPath = enviro & "\Documents\multipliers.xls"
```

to:

```
strPath = enviro & "\Documents\multipliers.xlsx"
```

Comment: good observation, now I am getting a different error which is "Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks Class" debug on this lineSet xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

Comment: Have you declared xlWB as a `Workbook`? e.g. `Dim xlWB As Workbook`

Comment: I have it dim to Dim xlWB As Object

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub doingstuff()
      Dim xlWB As Workbook
      On Error Resume Next
      Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
      If Err <> 0 Then
          Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
     Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     bXStarted = True
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
 strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & "\" & "Book2" & ".xlsm"
 Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
 End Sub
```

this works fine for me.

Comment: copied and paste Debug.Print strPath = enviro & "\Documents" & "\" & "multipliers.xlsx"   I am getting still a debug error on Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)